# MongoDB: Create Index for An embedded array

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way where I can create an index field for an document that is nested in an array of an outer document.

Here is a sample of the document
[image]

Inside the events array are another set of documents. 
[image]

I want to be able to create an index for each document within the events array.

For instance for Object 10, I want to add a new field idx: 10 and for object 11 add idx: 11 and so forth. What is a good way to do this in MongoDB?

Thanks

Comment: You can create multikey indexes on array fields that contain nested objects.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents

Comment: Do you wish to add a new `field` to a sub document and make the field act as an `index`? The title of the question and your description are contradicting.

Comment: yes that is what i want to do @BatScream

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested @Marco, But I am seeing the index being included in my events